# Hamiltonian paths & social graph algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, heuristics, np-complete, hamiltonian-cycle

I have a random undirected social graph.

I want to find a Hamiltonian path if possible. Or if not possible (or not possible to know if possible in polynomial time) a series of paths. In this "series of paths" (where all N nodes are used exactly once), I want to **minimize the number of paths** and **maximize the average length** of the paths. (So no trivial solution of N paths of a single node).

I have generated an adjacency matrix for the nodes and edges already.

Any suggestions? Pointers in the right direction? I realize this will require heuristics because of the NP-complete (?) nature of the problem, and I am OK with a "good enough" answer.  Also I would like to do this in Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a genetic algorithm (without crossover), where each individual is a permutation of the nodes. This gives you "series of paths" at each generation, evolving to a minimal number of paths (1) and a maximal avg. length (N).

Answer (score 2):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, what you're asking for is still NP-hard, since the best solution to the "multiple paths" problem would be a Hamiltonian path, and determining whether one exists is known to be NP-hard.  Moreover, even if you're guaranteed that a Hamiltonian path doesn't exist, solving this problem could still be NP-hard, since I could give you a graph with a single disconnected node floating in space, for which the best solution is a trivial path containing that node and a Hamiltonian path in the remaining graph.  As a result, unless P = NP, there isn't going to be a polynomial-time algorithm for your problem.

Hope this helps, and sorry for the negative result!

Comment: No, I mean having one trivial path as a point or two is not a real problem. And also I'm not looking for a complete answer, just a dirty "just enough" heuristic. any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Angluin and Valiant gave a near linear-time heuristic that works almost always in a sufficiently dense Erdos-Renyi random graph. It's described by [Wilf, on page 121](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AlgoComp.pdf). Probably your random graph is *not* Erdos-Renyi, but the heuristic might work anyway (when it "fails", it still gives you a (hopefully) long path; greedily take this path and run A-V again).

Answer (score 1):

As you have realized there is no exact solution in polynomial time. You can try some random search methods though. My recommendation, start with genetic algorithm and try out tabu search.